# Excel VBA mulitiple checkboxes

Tags: vba, checkbox, listbox

is it possible to create listbox with multiple checkboxes in one row (Excel VBA)?

Thanks
Kamil

Comment: As in `MultiSelect`, and `fmListStyleOption` but multiple columns?

Comment: No you can cannot have multiple checkboxes in a listbox row.  You could add controls to a frame at runtime to simulate a listbox.  Another alternative is to have two list-boxes side by side and sync them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question fully, but I'll elaborate on ListBoxes as much as I can.

- First things first: *Checkboxes* and *ListBoxes* are different objects in Excel Userforms. The first is the little box that returns a "true/false". The second is a list of items which can be chosen. Clicking in a Checkbox will make the tick mark appear/disappear (or fade if tristate is enabled), while clicking a Listbox row will turn the listbox row "blue"/"white" (or whatever color is being used for the selected rows). In both elements, clicking is a way to toggle between True and False.
- While a checkbox only allows for a single information to be marked as True or False, a Listbox allows you to select entries out of a list. That list may be inserted through code (.AddItem method) or passed from a range (.RowSource property)
- ListBox objects allow for multiple columns of data to be attributed to one row element, but each row is an entire element (which means you cannot pick the element on row 3, column 2 - only all of row 3). The number of columns is established using the ColumnCount property.
- By changing the value of the MultiSelect property, you'll allow the user to select multiple or single row elements simultaneously on your Listbox. Using the *Selected(* RowIndex *)* property, you can check whether or not an item is currently selected (returns True/False). Remember that row indexes start at 0.
- Finally, if you're using the *MultiSelect* property set to *fmMultiSelectSingle* and have a single column (as far as I know), the *Text* property can be used to return the selected item's value.

An easy example of a listbox is in Excel can be found at *File > Options > Customize Ribbon* (or something like that). There are two listboxes, one (on the left) with the visible items and another with the available items. A pair of command buttons is used to move items between boxes. That's a simple application you can likely find already setup online.

Am I on track to answer your question?